# Ubuntu from pendrive. How much space available

Tags: usb-drive, disk

I am currently trying ubuntu gnome which is mounted on a 2 GB pendrive. So, the computers internal hard disk (320 GB) is not used. So, I want to know how much space I have available. On running the command df -h in the terminal, I see this -

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/cow            1.9G  636M  1.3G  33% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           387M  1.3M  386M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       1.9G  923M  979M  49% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      882M  882M     0 100% /rofs
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G   96K  1.9G   1% /tmp
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  1.1M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       290G  374M  275G   1% /media/ubuntu-gnome/9e05a859-dc89-4e59-be8a-73d3e6da36e5
```

How can there be multiple partitions all 1.9GB when the whole pendrive is 2GB? Also, I downloaded 300 MB video file and none of these numbers changed. I then deleted it and still no change. This leaves me very confused. I want to know how much leeway I have to download stuff in this state.

Also, I see a 316 GB partition which is probably the internal disk in the file browser (it says "316 GB volume"), but am unable to create new folders or paste stuff to it. Is it possible to use that to store files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is an artifact. There really is only one 1.9GB partition. /tmp for example is a tmpfs, ie it is in memory, yet it shows up. A command to use if you have it is **findmnt** which shows you the hierarchy and where the real disks are.

When you download a large file the Avail column should change.

You should be able to use the `/media/...` disk, but you need to first create a directory on it for your user id. Use `sudo mkdir` and the full pathname of the directory, then `sudo chown user` and the same directory. Replace `user` by whatever you are logged in as (try `who am i`).